# I was creating a lucky no. generator in python in vscode but when i am using random module i am getting module not found error?

Tags: python, random, module

So I tried making a lucky no generator in which the user provides the input no. between (0,100) using **random.randint** but while using import random command is gives module not found error in vscode, I also tried it in other compiler i.e. jupyter and it works fine in it, can someone tell me how can I solve this issue.[I have attached an image of my code and error in which Iam getting the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC69E.png)

To resolve this issue, I tried **pip install random** command in terminal expecting the problem will be resolve but I got command not found error I don't know what Iam doing wrong. [I have attached the image of command I used to install module but got an error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdReX.png)

Comment: `random` is module in Standard Library, so definitely not `pip` install

Comment: It looks like there is some problem with python installation itself. How did you install python? Do you have problem with import of other moduled from standard library?

Comment: can you tell me how can I solve this error Iam only getting this error in vs code not in other compilers.  i simply installed latest version of python

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: sorry but Iam new to Stack overflow so didn't knew about it I will keep it in mind from next time thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

The random module is inbuilt in python so you don't need to install it via pip.

Comment: This should be a comment. It's not an answer